# Подключение по сокетам

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Есть хостинг, а именно `https://ru.000webhost.com/` (может как-то поможет в решении вопроса), нужно к нему как-то обратиться по сокетам, без ip адреса. Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Можете уточнить, что именно значит "обратиться к хостингу", "обратиться по сокетам" и "обратиться без IP-адреса"?

Answer (score 1):

Вам бы подучить мат.часть, но если в двух словах, то попробую объяснить на пальцах...
Сокет - это пара IP+port. IP нужен для того, чтобы найти компьютер в сети, порт-условное число, необходимое, чтобы понять, какая программа должна обрабатывать запрос через сеть, который пришел к компьютеру, найденному по ip. А вот компьютер, который дежурит на определенном порте и IP называется неожиданно сервер.
Без этого самого сервера никакого сайта не будет.
https://ru.000webhost.com/ - эту запись придумали для удобства человека, под ней скрывается реальный IP сервера, который обработает этот запрос.
В свете сказанного попробуйте сами оценить абсурдность своего вопроса...
Но в итоге мы имеем необходимость прочитать сайт https://ru.000webhost.com/ средствами Java, делается это так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL("https://ru.000webhost.com/").openStream(), "UTF-8");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

Получите построчно HTML в консоль.
Разумеется, это "закат солнца вручную", но в свете вопроса, думаю , что этот код стоит освоить.